# What kind of clues can I give players to help them track down a thief?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm new to DMing. I'm writing some quests for a campaign my friends have shown interest in. This particular quest involves a missing ring. It was stolen from a window sill of the owner's home by a man who just so happened to come across it for the brief moment it was unattended. The man then tries to pawn the ring at a shop, but is unable to come to an arrangement and leaves.

I can't seem to come up with an acceptable clue to give players to check that shop. While it is a known location they've been to before and I'm positive one of them will quickly think to check there, you can never be 100% certain what someone will do so I'd like to come up with a clue or two to help direct them there.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Idea generation questions like this don’t work well with our format here, but your question may be on topic at a traditional discussion forum, see [here for our curated list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Answer (score 4):

### The shop is not important

Or, rather, you seem to be making it the only link between the players and the thief, which is making it needlessly important. This goes totally against the [three clue rule](https://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/1118/roleplaying-games/three-clue-rule).

As stated, the problem *appears* to be identifying the thief. Or maybe it's finding the thief. Of course, if the *actual* problem is recovering the ring, then there are plenty of ways of doing that without ever identifying or finding the thief. I suggest that you need to think about what the actual quest *is* and then you can start to think about the situations that go into resolving it.

Notwithstanding, let's assume that *one* of the goals is identifying the thief. We need at least three *obvious and unambiguous* clues that will allow the party to go from "we don't know who the thief is" to "we now know who the thief is".

The shop is a clue. If the players have fenced stolen items there before, they might think of it themselves. If they can ask where one might fence stolen goods, that can lead them to the shop. If they don't think of the shop or don't ask around, then they don't get this clue.

That's why you need at least two others.